# How to use substr and strrchr in a loop

Tags: php, sql

Overall Description : I have a random value that looks like sample, but may have more to the value of m, example : m4, or m8 before the model #

How would I use my substr code sample within the foreach loop to get substr output for each item of isset($item[whatever])?

// substr and strrchr code sample(that works on $sample)

```
<?php
$sample = 'm1:m2:m3:ModelNum';
$model= substr(strrchr($item, ":"), 1);
echo $model; // "ModelNum"
?>
```

// start loop

```
<?php foreach ( $invoice['InvoiceDetail'] as $key=>$item){?>
```

// sample item in loop

```
<td style="text-align: left"> <?php echo isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id'] : ''; ?></td>
```

Comment: I quite dont understand the question. You can do with $item whatever you want within your loop. Certainly also modify the data eg. by using your functions from above.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit hard to find out what you want. Can you use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: @FirstOne : the substr works perfectly, researched and know how to use it, I am not familiar with explode.  basically i have to take a string, and echo out the very LAST chars AFTER the LAST ":"

Comment: @Steven Well, you could combine explode with [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php). Something like this: `$last = array_pop(explode(':', $a));` where `$a` is the variable with `'Manufacturer:SubManufacturer:SubSubManufacturer:ModelNum'`. The output is, in this case: `ModelNum`. **But** I don't understand your question, if you said that it works, what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @FirstOne my code works for one value that I set, I need to find out how to get it to work with the loop I included

Comment: @Steven, are you saying that each `$item` from the `foreach` is a string like that `m1:mn` example? It's so hard to get what you mean. Please, elaborate on sample input and provide expected output...

Answer (score 0):

decide how many manufacturer values you want to display... this code will display 3 and the model num

```
$sample = 'val1:val2:val3:val4';
$values = explode(':', $sample);
$modelNum = array_pop($values);
for ($i=0, $i<4, $i++) {
    echo isset($values[$i])
        ? $values[$i]
        : '';
}
echo $modelNum;
```

Comment: That would work perfect, and I understand the concept of explode, but the problem is, sometimes there will be 2 manufacturers, sometimes 5, etc, so how would I pull out consistently the last value of the array?

Comment: does it vary from row to row, or will all the items you're iterating over be the same?   what's the minimum number of values?   if it's always  manufacturer.... manufacturerx, modelnum...  you can `array_pop` off the modelnum, `array_slice`, `array_splice`, and other funcs may be able to help you

Comment: Its not always ma,mb,mc,model - sometimes there are more, sometimes less.  I know that the code I posted works on the sample variable, I just dont know how to tie it into the looped $items([whatever])

Comment: updated answer..   question and requirements are still quite vague

Comment: I have x amount of categories.  x may = 2, x may = 5.  However, at the end of x is ALWAYS the model #.  Any code set to a specific # for x will not work, basically I just need to parse it to where it sees ":" for the last time, and return the characters after that